# React redux two states conflict

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have two reducers in my redux mention below -

```
case actionTypes.SENT_REQUEST_FAIL:
      return {
showAlert: true, 
}
case actionTypes.GET_STUDENT_PROFILE_BY_PROFILEID_SUCCESS:
      return {
   showAlert: false,
}
```

and i need showAlert:true in some case but last reducer call is GET_STUDENT_PROFILE_BY_PROFILEID_SUCCESS , so always showAlert become false. how do i run SENT_REQUEST_FAIL in end to get true value.

```
 const cardData = async (val1, val2, val3) => {
    setshowsentRequestModal(false);
    handleModal(false);
    //this is true one
    await props.sentRequest(val1, val2, val3);
  };
```

```
  const handleModal = (val) => {
    props.handleSentRequestModal(val);
    //this is false one
    props.getStudentProfileByProfileId(studentId);
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

In your approach, state is not update. It always return the initial value.
you need to pass the current state to reducer and update it as below.

```
case actionTypes.SENT_REQUEST_FAIL:
  return {
...state, showAlert: true
};
case actionTypes.GET_STUDENT_PROFILE_BY_PROFILEID_SUCCESS:
 return {
...state, showAlert: false
};
```

Comment: i have it, but forgot to mention in code, because of many other states